# Integrate $\frac{x}{1+x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate something like this? $$\int \frac{x}{1+x^4}\mathrm{d}x$$

I've tried trig substitutions but none have worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u = x^2$. Then $\,du = 2x \,dx $.

$$\int \dfrac x{1 + x^4} \,dx = \dfrac 12 \int \dfrac{2x\,dx}{1 + (x^2)^2} = \dfrac 12 \int \dfrac{\,du}{1 + u^2}$$

Then use the trigonometric substitution $u = \tan \theta$.